# Motion in Crafty.js

Tags: javascript, craftyjs

Im trying to use the `Motion` component in crafty.js but I fail at the most basic things. It seems like the 'Motion' component is not added.

Like this very simple code [from example code in the docs](http://craftyjs.com/api/Motion.html#-velocity).

```
var ent = Crafty.e("2D, Motion");

var vel = ent.velocity(); //returns the velocity vector
vel.x;       // retrieve the velocity in the x direction
vel.x = 0;   // set the velocity in the x direction
vel.x += 4   // add to the velocity in the x direction
```

result: `TypeError: ent.velocity is not a function`

I can access functions in other components like `Multivay`, `Text` just fine.

Comment: Check the Crafty version you are using. It was added with [0.7](https://github.com/craftyjs/Crafty/releases/tag/0.7.0). The code should work as in [this JSBin](http://jsbin.com/bohoxovuwa/edit?html,js,console,output)

Comment: Ouch how embarrassing, while having the 0.7.0 crafty.js in my directory I was hot-linking a crafty.min.js of 0.6.3. sorry for this..

Comment: When in doubt, [`Crafty.getVersion()`](http://craftyjs.com/api/Crafty-getVersion.html) to the rescue

Comment: Yes, well I wasn't in doubt, hehe. I should have been thou..